# How to import UTF 8 CSV files using the Table Data Import Wizerd in MySQL Workbench

Tags: csv, import, utf-8, mysql-workbench

I have a couple of csv files that where exported from Excel into a UTF8 csv format. According to the BOM and content Excel indeed generates a UTF-8 file.
When I attempt the Table Data Import Wizard from MySQL workbench these files are not correctly imported and out of ASCII characters are mangled. For instance `ł` is imported as `Å‚` . In the wizard the encoding is set as UTF-8 as per

[image]

But it seems this is ignored. I know there is a way with an SQL IMPORT FILE command but the import ultimately has to be done by someone not very versed in SQL.